# how can i split a string C#

Tags: c#, string, split

i have a string, something like this:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.
```

and i have to split it.

the first 8, then the next 4 and so on.

Edit: i would prefer to define the length of the pieces in a separate file.
and the program to get the length form the external file.

- Program (length1=a)
- File (a=8)

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Also, is this homework? if it is, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: First 8, next 4, next 2, next 1, then what, next ½?

Comment: no, it's not homework. the numbers are random, not divided by 2.
i get this string from an PBX.

Comment: You have too many questions in one question. First you should ask a question about string splitting, with more detailed examples of how the strings should be splitted, then you create another question about how to add strings to a database.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say "the first 8, then the next 4 and so on." What does the "and so on" part look like? Is it "8,4,8,4,8,4..."? "8,4,2,1"? A set of numbers to be provided at run time?  My approach would change depending on how this is supposed to work.

Comment: it's something linek 8,4,1,10,4,5,3,2. no exact order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

```
var field1 = myString.Substring(0,8);
var field2 = myString.Substring(8,4);
```

and so on.

Comment: thanks for the help. can i use `var field1 =myString.Substring(a)` and `a="0, 8"`?

Comment: @sebastian: You have to get the 0 and 8 separately from your configuration data source, and present them to the SubString methods as `int` values.

Answer (score 4):

**To divide a string, you can use the [`String.SubString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method.** It has an overload that accepts a starting position and a length:

```
string input = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";

string sub1 = input.SubString(0, 8);
string sub2 = input.SubString(8, 4);
// and so on.
```

**To insert the data into a database you need to use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28VS.71%29.aspx).** There are many examples online for doing this. Hopefully the link to MSDN will get you started.

Comment: thanks for the help.
can i use `string sub1 =input.Substring(a)`?
and a="0, 8"?

Comment: That's not how method arguments work. You can, however, declare two separate variables for each parameter, and pass them in: `int a = 0; int b = 8; string sub1 = input.SubString(a,b);`. This can make it easier to implement the logic as a loop and to avoid having to hardcode the starting index for each substring operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would first change that string into char[] and then using some extra variables print out (or whatever you need to do with it).

Comment: What does changing it into a char[] add?  A string is already enumerable and indexable.

Comment: That depends of the future usage of that string. But i mouse cases rally nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses LINQ to take a set of characters based on a list of specified "pages."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//...
public static void TestStringSplit()
{
    var s = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.";
    var chars = s.ToCharArray().AsEnumerable();
    var pages = new List<int>() { 8, 4, 5, 3, 50, 50 };
    var output = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count; i++)
    {
        var page = pages[i];

        output.Add(String.Join("",
            chars.Skip(pages.Where((p, j) => j < i).Sum(p => p)).Take(page)
            ));
    }

    output.ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine(o));
}
```

returns:

```
12345678
9012
34567
890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.
```

In the above example,

- The `pages` variable represents the the size of each substring that you want to take from the main string.
- The `Skip` LINQ expression is skipping all of the characters that have already been "paged."
- The `Take` LINQ expression is returning a group of characters that match the size you are expecting.

The advantage of using an enumerable of `char`s is that you don't get index out of range exceptions in the `Skip` call like you normally would with a `Substring` call.

How you fill the `pages` variable with data and how you get the values in `output` into your database is dependent on your implementation, but this should give you a good start.